# Can enterprise App Read its MDM Configuration file?

Tags: applications, mobile-device-management, enterprise

I have the following situation -

There is a school which distribute number of iPads to students, which deploy in-house app for student.
Basically the app will display the PDFs, Images and Videos form remote server.

Now the challenge is that, Class 1 student needs to fetch PDfs, Images and Videos form one link
where as Class 2 student needs to fetch PDfs, Images and Videos form another link.
Class 1 and Class 2 devices are managed via MDM server in corresponding Groups.

Now the app need to know which device group, the current device is enrolled into.
As we know the device Groups info is set via MDM server.

So the question is - is there anyways enterprise app can get information from MDM server about the device group it is enrolled in, so that it can change its app feature as per device group ?

Is there way to read the device configuration file via app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the devices are enrolled in an MDM server, I would suggest using Managed App Configuration:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html

Managed App Config was introduced in iOS 7 and allows the MDM server to 'push' a dictionary to the managed app's NSUserDefaults container, essentially allowing for remote configuration of the app.

As you already have devices in separate groups, you should be able to configure your MDM to assign different managed app configurations to devices in each group.

Comment: How about in android ? Do you have any idea how this can be handle in android